# Hibernate Joins

Tags: hibernate, join

Please how to write this simple working select, in Hibernate query or criteria

```
SELECT * FROM `call` AS c JOIN `event_customer` AS e ON c.customer_id = e.customer_id WHERE e.dgdelete = FALSE AND c.eventruletype_id = 1 AND e.event_id = 74 AND c.callactivity_id = 3 AND e.calltype = 2
```

I found already many advices, but nothing helped me, yet.

It could be something with hibernate mapping ?

Thank you.

ps:
this is not working

```
query = session.createQuery("select c from " + Call.class.getSimpleName()+ " as c " + EventCustomer.class.getSimpleName()+ " as e where e.customer_id = c.customer_id and e.event_id = 74");
```

also this not working

```
 query = session.createQuery("select c from " + Call.class.getSimpleName()+ " as c join " + EventCustomer.class.getSimpleName()+ " as e where e.customer_id = c.customer_id and e.event_id = 74");
```

and also this

```
 query = session.createQuery("select c from " + Call.class.getSimpleName()+ " as c join " + EventCustomer.class.getSimpleName()+ " as e on e.customer_id = c.customer_id  where  e.event_id = 74");
```

and also this

```
query = session.createQuery("select c from " + Call.class.getSimpleName()+ " as c left join " + EventCustomer.class.getSimpleName()+ " as e on e.customer_id = c.customer_id  where  e.event_id = 74");
```

and in some cases i get this error

Comment: In what way do the queries you gave not work? What happens vs. what you expected? What is your database schema and Java data model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. (replace JOIN with comma)

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("select c from " + Call.class.getSimpleName() + " as c , " + EventCustomer.class.getSimpleName() + " as e where e.customer.id = c.customer.id and c.event.id = 74");
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont concatenate, instead use criteria:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Call.class, "c")
    .createCriteria("eventCustomerDto","e")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("event_id",74));
List<Call> list=crit.list();
```

The code may have typos but thats the idea. Also, for my example, i asumed there is a one-to-many relationship on Call hibernate mapping between Call and EventCustomer.

Comment: Man this is not good, how you can write down createCriteria(*).createCriteria ??

Comment: it's a function of the criteria instance, it returns another criteria for the specified Dto, which i used to add the restriction to.